# Do I pay any fee to the miner if I call a non-constant function, when no state variable is changed?

Tags: gas, gas-estimate

Suppose I have a non-constant function which changes a state variable under some condition.

In other words, the function may sometimes change this variable and sometimes leave it as is.

Will I pay any gas fee to the miner when the function doesn't change the variable?

I wrote a small Truffle test which shows the gas cost when the function doesn't change the variable:

**File MyContract.sol:**

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract MyContract {
    uint private x;

    constructor(uint _x) public {
        x = _x;
    }

    function set() external {
        if (x >= 42)
            x += 42;
    }

    function get() external view returns (uint) {
        return x;
    }
}
```

**File MyContract.js:**

```
contract("MyContractTest", function(accounts) {
    it("set", async function() {
        let myContract = await artifacts.require("MyContract.sol").new(41);
        let estimateGas = await myContract.set.estimateGas();
        console.log(estimateGas);
    });
    it("get", async function() {
        let myContract = await artifacts.require("MyContract.sol").new(41);
        let estimateGas = await myContract.get.estimateGas();
        console.log(estimateGas);
    });
});
```

**The Printout**:

```
Contract: MyContractTest set: 21647
Contract: MyContractTest get: 21656
```

I then realized that `estimateGas` runs under the assumption that the tested function is called from the on-chain (i.e., by some other contract) and not from the off-chain, because the gas cost of the constant function `get` was also larger than 0.

So as in the title of my question:

Will I pay any fee to the miner if I call function `set` and it doesn't change variable `x`?

Thank you!

**CLARIFICATION:**

My question is about the gas cost of a **non-constant** function (can it be zero in some cases). The question suggested as a duplicate is about the gas cost of a **constant** function (can it be larger than zero in some cases). So these are essentially two different questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constant functions and gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34739/constant-functions-and-gas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The non-constant (not `pure`, `view` or `constant`) would be invoked by a transaction to be *potentially* state-changing. A transaction is mined and confirmed by all full nodes to find out what it does. Even if it does nothing as a result of conditional branching, the sender pays for the gas consumed forming network consensus.

In more detail: https://blog.b9lab.com/calls-vs-transactions-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-62d6b17d0bc2

Hope it helps.